# "Forthcoming paper" of Goldston-Graham-Pintz-Yıldırım

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, journals

The above-named authors of [1] and its (significantly different) published version [2] write:

> In a forthcoming paper, we will show how the methods here can be extended to prove corresponding results for an arbitrary shift $b$. In particular, we can prove that for any positive integer $b$, there are infinitely many integers $x$ such that $x$ and $x + b$ have the same exponent pattern.

Does anyone know if this paper, or another containing a similar result, has been made public (preprint, publication, etc.)? This question subsumes as special cases the existence of infinitely many $n$ with $d(n)=d(n+b)=m$ or $\Omega(n)=\Omega(n+b)=m$ or $\omega(n)=\omega(n+b)=m$ etc.

[1] D. A. Goldston, S. W. Graham, J. Pintz, and C. Y. Yıldırım, Small gaps between almost primes, the parity problem, and some conjectures of Erdős on consecutive integers (2008). [arXiv:0803.2636](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2636)

[2] D. A. Goldston, S. W. Graham, J. Pintz, and C. Y. Yıldırım, Small gaps between almost primes, the parity problem, and some conjectures of Erdős on consecutive integers, *International Mathematics Research Notices* **2011**:7, pp. 1439–1450.

Comment: You can search arXiv... http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Yildirim_C/0/1/0/all/0/1

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I did, actually, without result. But many papers aren't posted there, and sometimes other papers from different authors supersede results from 'forthcoming' papers so I thought it was worthwhile asking.