# Are there an infinite number of twin semiprimes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

A [semiprime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiprime.html) is a number that is the
product of two (possibly equal) primes.
Define *twin semiprimes* (my terminology) as two consecutive numbers both semiprimes.
For example, $(57,58)$ are twin semiprimes because $57=3 \cdot 19$ and $58=2 \cdot 29$.
And $(622,623)$ are twin semiprimes because $622=2 \cdot 311$ and $623=7 \cdot 89$.
The semiprimes (a.k.a. biprimes or 2-almost primes) are integer sequence [A001358](https://oeis.org/A001358).

> ***Q***. Is it known that there are an infinite number of twin semiprimes?

At least superficially, the twin semiprimes seem abundant,
as this histogram of their frequency out to $n=10^6$ shows:

---

[image: TwinSemiPrimes]

---

Comment: No, we don't know this.  Chen's theorem gives that there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which $p+2$ has at most two prime factors, but the sieve has a ``parity problem" preventing one from getting numbers with exactly two prime factors.  In other words, we can say $n(n+2)$ can have two or three prime factors, but not exactly two prime factors (or exactly three, or four).

Comment: @Lucia, note that Joseph is asking about $n$ and $n+1$, not $n$ and $n+2$ (although I suspect the answer is the same).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, I didn't spot that, but the same comments apply -- we don't know how to make the sequence $n(n+1)$ have exactly an even number of prime factors (like $4$).

Comment: There should be recent results that give some hope, namely that $\omega(n)=\omega(n+1)$ for infinitely many $n$.  However it does not settle Joseph's question.  Gerhard "Remembering Results For Other Functions" Paseman, 2015.09.05

Comment: @Lucia: Thank you for that definitive answer, and for pointing to [*Chen's Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem).

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Indeed, as I asked about here: http://mathoverflow.net/q/212026/6043

Comment: Obligatory OEIS reference: [A070552](https://oeis.org/A070552).